# C++ cast object to its original type

Tags: c++, casting

What i want to achieve is this following behavior:

```
int main(){
   vector<Component*>v = {...};
   draw(dynamic_cast< ??? >v[0]);
}
 void draw(const Image& i){...}
 void draw(const Text& i){...}
 void draw(const Link& i){...}
```

where `Image, Text, Link` are derive classes from `Component`, but i don't know what to put inside the `< >` of the dynamic cast, or at least if there is another way to do this.

For the moment, what i was thinking is to use `variant`, but to get the element i need to call `std::get` where i have to specify the type, and so at the same point.

So at this point i think that the only way is to create a list of `if(dynamic_cast<>(v[0])` with all the possible type...

Comment: I think what you want can be achieved. Google " Sean parent inheritance is the base class of evil". Even if it's not quite what you need. It's still a good lecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do end up using a `variant`, you can use `std::visit` to work out which form of your draw function to call as long as you don't need other arguments, or they all take the same arguments after the type:

```
for ( auto & vitem : in v ) // where v is a vector of variant
  std::visit([](auto && shape){ draw( shape ); }, vitem);
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit for more details.

Comment: sorry but the lambda parameter is auto, how can the compiler deduce the type if one time is a Text, then is a Image, then is a Link (for example)?

Comment: @Berto99 `std::visit()` is a bit complex internally (there are explanations online if you look around), but in a nutshell it uses template trickery to create an invokation of the lambda *for every possible type the `std::variant` supports at compile time*, thus allowing the lambda to use an `auto` parameter, and then it decides which of those implementions to actually invoke at runtime based on `vItem.index()`

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to cast to, because `vector<Component>` can only contain objects of type `Component`. It cannot contain any derived objects. Static type can differ from the dynamic type only through indirection.

Now, if we had a case that you had a reference to base class for example, there would be no way at compile time to know the dynamic type, thus there is nothing that you could write into `dynamic_cast<???>` that would make this work.

The way dynamic polymorphism is achieved through inheritance is to instead pass a reference to base into the `draw` function, and then use virtual member functions of `Component` in order to have different behaviour based on the dynamic type.

Comment: i'm so sorry, i was missing the * in vector in order to point to a base class, and so to be able to contain also derived classes

Comment: The advice about using `virtual` functions is still relevant

Comment: yes, but for example draw in that case should get something to draw on, and so i'll create a dependency between my Components and my graphic library

Comment: @Berto99 You can use visitor pattern to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you are asking for, you would have to test for every type individually, eg:

```cpp
void draw(const Image& i) { ... }
void draw(const Text& i) { ... }
void draw(const Link& i) { ... }

int main() {
   vector<Component*> v = {...};
   ...   
   if (Image *img = dynamic_cast<Image*>(v[0]))
      draw(img);
   else if (Text *txt = dynamic_cast<Text*>(v[0]))
      draw(txt);
   else if (Link *lnk = dynamic_cast<Link*>(v[0]))
      draw(lnk);
   ...
}
```

Needless to say, this is not a good approach.  `draw()` should instead be a `virtual` method of `Component` and then each subclass can `override` it as needed, eg:

```cpp
class Component
{
public:
   ...
   virtual void draw() { ... }
   ...
};

class Image : public Component
{
public:
   ...
   void draw() override { ... }
   ...
};

class Text : public Component
{
public:
   ...
   void draw() override { ... }
   ...
};

class Link : public Component
{
public:
   ...
   void draw() override { ... }
   ...
};

int main() {
   vector<Component*> v = {...};
   ...   
   v[0]->draw();
   ...
}
```

Comment: yes, sure, but my component are created to be drawn, but it's not a your job... infact if i create a method draw, i should pass them a sort of Layout of Graphic object to draw on, and so i create a dependency between my logic and my graphic engine

Comment: The caller (ie `main`) decides what type of graphic is drawn onto, the components don't have to care about that, they just need to decide HOW they are drawn, which should very much be their jobs, not the job of external functions.  This approach actually decouples the components from the engine, not links them together

Comment: i'm sorry but how can a component be able to draw something if the method has no parameter?

Comment: @Berto99 obviously, you would have to add a parameter, or add a field to `Component`, or make a global. Your original example had the same requirement.